# How to create Excel file with right-to-left sheet column order in React?

Tags: reactjs, export-to-excel

The following code works fine and generates `file.xlsx`.

Question: How to set the sheets columns to right-to-left order?

```
import React from 'react'
import * as FileSaver from "file-saver";
import * as XLSX from "xlsx";

export const ExportToExcel = ({ apiData, fileName }) => {
  const fileType =
    "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet;charset=UTF-8";
  const fileExtension = ".xlsx";

  const exportToXL = (apiData, fileName) => {
    const ws = XLSX.utils.json_to_sheet(apiData);
    const wb = { Sheets: { data: ws, data2: ws }, SheetNames: ["data", "data2"] };
    const excelBuffer = XLSX.write(wb, { bookType: "xlsx", type: "array" });
    const data = new Blob([excelBuffer], { type: fileType });
    FileSaver.saveAs(data, fileName + fileExtension);
  };

  return (
    <button onClick={(e) => exportToXL(apiData, fileName)}>Export</button>
  );
};
```

Answer (score 1):

Need to add property per sheet, like the following:

```
    var wb = { Sheets: { data: ws, data2: ws }, SheetNames: ["data", "data2"], Workbook: { Views: [{RTL:true}, {RTL:true} ]} }
```

Note the `Workbook` field.